# How to make a on select dropdown to hide and show vue js form wizard tab?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

i have make a form wizard using vue js and in step five but i want to on select dropdown to middl step like third and fourth step hide and show using index.

see this plugin : https://cristijora.github.io/vue-form-wizard/#/?id=methods

whene select hide :
[image]

And whene select show :

[image]

```
Wizard.vue

<template>
  <div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <select name="" id="">
        <option value="hide">hide</option>
        <option value="show">show</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <form-wizard @on-complete="onComplete">
      <tab-content title="first"
                    icon="ti-user">
        first
      </tab-content>
      <tab-content title="second"  icon="ti-settings">
        second
      </tab-content>
      <tab-content title="four" icon="ti-settings">
        four
      </tab-content>
      <tab-content title="five"
                    icon="ti-settings">
        five
      </tab-content>
      <tab-content title="Last step"
                    icon="ti-check">
        Yuhuuu! This seems pretty damn simple
      </tab-content>
    </form-wizard>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Do you want to hide every tab-content when hide is selected in your select dropdown?

Comment: no only second and four <tab-content > hide show using index because it's show using array just now i add static

Comment: see update my question

Comment: How do I solve this situation?

Answer (score 0):

First add the option value as myVal in `data` of Wrapper component.

You can use conditional rendering. [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

```
v-if="myVal === 'hide'"
```

**directive** to hide and show elements.

For styling we can add

```
.tab-container {
   display:flex,
   justify-content: space-between
}
```